# How to understand the grammar of "strength were granted me"?

Tags: grammar, passive-voice, subject-verb-inversion

I find the following sentence from a translation of Proust's *In search of lost time*:

> But at least, if strength were granted me for long enough to accomplish my
> work, ...

I want to understand it better. I think that the grammatical usage of the phrase "for long enough" is like that of "for 14 days", "for ten years", etc. Simplifying it, we have

> if strength were granted me to accomplish my work, ...

Then I am confused about the part "strength were granted me". Is it an inversion with passive voice? Can I understand the sentence as: "if I was granted strength to accomplish my work"?

Comment: Your understanding of the sentence is correct. I don't know the technicalities to explain why though, so I won't post an answer.

Comment: To my mind it's archaic English that's seldom used today.

Comment: "were" is a subjunctive or irrealis, depending on your terminology, expressing a counterfactual or hypothetical. In less formal English you would say "if strength was granted to me". (But it's Proust, so flowery language is required.)